# How to get a bookmarklet to pop up a form that submits URL and Title to DB plus comments

Tags: php, javascript, forms, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet implemented that when clicked sends the URL and Title to a DB. I would like a form to pop up first that has a field to add comments, a field for editing the page title, and a drop down field for selecting a category that is populated from a DB table.

I'm still learning php with barely any JS skills. I don't know how to get the bookmarklet to call a pop form that will submit to a DB or pass the page URL and Title to a form.

The code I have used so far is from here -> http://tutorialzine.com/2010/04/simple-bookmarking-app-php-javascript-mysql/

Bookmarklet Code:

```
(function () {
  var jsScript = document.createElement('script');
  jsScript.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
  jsScript.setAttribute('src', '/bookmark.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(location.href)
  + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(document.title));

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jsScript);

})();
```

Bookmark.php Code:

```
// Error reporting:
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

require "connect.php";
require "functions.php";

// Setting the content-type header to javascript:
header('Content-type: application/javascript');

// Validating the input data
if(empty($_GET['url']) || empty($_GET['title']) || !validateURL($_GET['url'])) die();

// Sanitizing the variables
$_GET['url'] = sanitize($_GET['url']);
$_GET['title'] = sanitize($_GET['title']);

// Inserting, notice the use of the hash field and the md5 function:
mysql_query("   INSERT INTO bookmark_app (hash,url,title)
                VALUES (
                    '".md5($_GET['url'])."',
                    '".$_GET['url']."',
                    '".$_GET['title']."'
                )");

$message = '';
if(mysql_affected_rows($link)!=1)
{
    $message = 'This URL already exists in the database!';
}
else
$message = 'The URL was shared!';


?>

/* JavaScript Code */

function displayMessage(str)
{
    // Using pure JavaScript to create and style a div element

    var d = document.createElement('div');

    with(d.style)
    {
        // Applying styles:

        position='fixed';
        width = '350px';
        height = '20px';
        top = '50%';
        left = '50%';
        margin = '-30px 0 0 -195px';
        backgroundColor = '#f7f7f7';
        border = '1px solid #ccc';
        color = '#777';
        padding = '20px';
        fontSize = '18px';
        fontFamily = '"Myriad Pro",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif';
        textAlign = 'center';
        zIndex = 100000;

        textShadow = '1px 1px 0 white';

        MozBorderRadius = "12px";
        webkitBorderRadius = "12px";
        borderRadius = "12px";

        MozBoxShadow = '0 0 6px #ccc';
        webkitBoxShadow = '0 0 6px #ccc';
        boxShadow = '0 0 6px #ccc';
    }

    d.setAttribute('onclick','document.body.removeChild(this)');

    // Adding the message passed to the function as text:
    d.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));

    // Appending the div to document
    document.body.appendChild(d);

    // The message will auto-hide in 3 seconds:

    setTimeout(function(){
        try{
            document.body.removeChild(d);
        }   catch(error){}
    },3000);
}

<?php 

// Adding a line that will call the JavaScript function:
echo 'displayMessage("'.$message.'");';

?>
```

Functions.php

```
<?php

/* Helper functions */

function validateURL($str)
{
    return preg_match('/(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;\/~\+#])?/i',$str);
}

function sanitize($str)
{
    if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc'))
        $str = stripslashes($str);

    $str = strip_tags($str);
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = htmlspecialchars($str);
    $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);

    return $str;
}


function relativeTime($dt,$precision=2)
{
    if(is_string($dt)) $dt = strtotime($dt);

    $times=array(   365*24*60*60    => "year",
                    30*24*60*60     => "month",
                    7*24*60*60      => "week",
                    24*60*60        => "day",
                    60*60           => "hour",
                    60              => "minute",
                    1               => "second");

    $passed=time()-$dt;

    if($passed<5)
    {
        $output='less than 5 seconds ago';
    }
    else
    {
        $output=array();
        $exit=0;

        foreach($times as $period=>$name)
        {
            if($exit>=$precision || ($exit>0 && $period<60)) break;

            $result = floor($passed/$period);
            if($result>0)
            {
                $output[]=$result.' '.$name.($result==1?'':'s');
                $passed-=$result*$period;
                $exit++;
            }
            else if($exit>0) $exit++;
        }

        $output=implode(' and ',$output).' ago';
    }

    return $output;
}

// Defining fallback functions for mb_substr and 
// mb_strlen if the mb extension is not installed:

if(!function_exists('mb_substr'))
{
    function mb_substr($str,$start,$length,$encoding)
    {
        return substr($str,$start,$length);
    }
}

if(!function_exists('mb_strlen'))
{
    function mb_strlen($str,$encoding)
    {
        return strlen($str);
    }
}
?>
```

The end result I would like to have is some thing like the Bitly bookmarklet, https://bitly.com/a/tools, but I just need help linking the Bookmarklet to a pop up form that submits to a db.

I've tried looking around at other peoples questions but I coudln't find any that applied to using a pop up form to submit to a DB.

Comment: post the full bookmarklet code please.

Comment: I see, you use get for the feedback. At first I thought to have the bookmarklet generate the form (posting the data instead of get), but that would indeed disrupt the feedback. So you'd have to change the bookmark.php to operate in 2 stages. 
`if (hash exists in db) {
   alert url already shared;
} else if (form submit) {
   add entry to db;
   alert url shared;
} else {
   display form;
}`  In case of the form submit, either go json, or insert another javascript with a geturl and submit-variable. Is this what you are after?

Comment: I get what your saying but I don't no enough JS at this point to code the form and "if" statements. The code above I picked up from a tutorial online as it was the closest example that would teach me what I want to do. I think I need a snipet of the "if" statement that would just bring up even a one field form that I could expand on. I hate learning one language and needing to know others to get done what I'm working done, but that part of learning process. I'm quickly learning that JS is probably the next skill I really need to work on next to php.

Comment: You would not really need a form. Just a couple of input-fields, a text-area and a select-box (populated from db). However javascript has to populate the selectbox with values from the db. I already have some snippets for this question (but they don't add up to a full answer yet), but this question is quite elaborate actually. The tools you need for this are javascript, html, php, sql and probably some json. Also, the current code has no database-fields for comments and 'category' (I guess). Still a lot of blanks to fill.

Comment: ¡That's exactly what I'm looking for! Were you able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just append the HTML form in the bookmarklet ( the javascript ).

`var HTML = '<form action=""><input type="text" name="title" /></form>';
 document.appendChild(HTML);`

This is not a complete code , just an example of the principle that can help do your job.